# Is it cheaper to call round function or to operate with float?

Tags: javascript, performance

Say I got a variable `x=651.6666463216146`

I plan to use it only once to position an SVG element. I wonder if it will be faster to call `Math.round()` to make it an integer or just pass it as is and let the browser's SVG interpreter deal with it? I don't know how to measure this kind performance.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Answer (score 1):

try binary operator `|`, i didn't see anything faster

```js
console.log(651.6666463216146|1)
```